# How to insert hyper link in a Label text?

Tags: java, hyperlink, vaadin

Does anybody know how hyperlink reference can be inserted into a Vaadin label? For example, I have

**label:**

```
Label label = new Label("Developed by Corporation);
```

I need to add on mouse-over link for the word "Corporation".

Comment: With setDescription you can set the mouse over tool tip. I don't know if there are <a href things allowed or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting HTML content for label should work for simple cases:

```
Label labelWithLink = 
    new Label("Developed by <a href='http://google.com'>Corporation</a>", ContentMode.HTML));
```

or, if you're using Vaadin 6:

```
Label labelWithLink = 
    new Label("Developed by <a href='http://google.com'>Corporation</a>", Label.CONTENT_XHTML));
```

You might want to add CSS styles to hard coded HTML if you want to change display options.